# Loop table to INSERT back to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a PHP page that queries a database, and populates multiple tables with values. Those values need to be modified and placed in a separate table.

I know how to look through the database to show all the tables, but I can't find anything about how to loop through the html tables to reinsert the new values. I can't simply use an id and a ton of functions because there is an indeterminate number of rows.

Here is a list of the columns in the table I am accessing:

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code that I am using to access the database and populate the tables:

```
function tableAddData( $tableNum )
{
    // Access Global Variables
    global $noteId, $itemId, $quantityId, $costId, $laborHoursId, $totalHoursId, $materialCostId, $laborCostId, $totalCostId, $itemNumberId, $servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $quantityChangeId, $qtyRow;

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "select
                `note`                                                          as `Note`,
                `item`                                                          as `Item`,
                `qty`                                                           as `Quantity`,
                `cost`                                                          as `Cost`,
                `hrsLabor`                                                      as `Labor Hours`,
                `rate`                                                          as `Labor Rate`,
                `qty` * `hrsLabor`                                              as `Total Hours`,
                FORMAT(`qty` * `cost`, 2)                                       as `Material Cost`,
                FORMAT(`qty` * `rate` * `hrsLabor`, 2)                          as `Labor Cost`,
                FORMAT(( `qty` * `cost` ) + ( `qty` * `hrsLabor` * `rate` ), 2) as `Total Cost`,
                `itemNo`                                                        as `Item Number`
            from
                `test_newtable`,
                labor_rates
            where
                test_newtable.laborRate = labor_rates.id AND test_newtable.tableNo = " . $tableNum . ";";


    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row["Note"] != "" ) {
                    $noteHtml = '<td id="Note" class="text-center">
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="' . $row["Note"] . '">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment text-danger"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </td>';
                }
            else {
                $noteHtml =  '<td></td>';
            };
            echo '
                <tr>'
                                                                                                    . $noteHtml                     . '
                    <td id="Item" >'            . '<input class="text-left" value="'    . $row["Item"]              . '" disabled/></td>
                    <td id="Quantity">'         . '<input class="text-center qty" id="qty-' . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Quantity"]          . '" /></td>
                    <td class="dollarRight" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0; width:20px;">' . '<input class="text-center text-muted" value="$"  disabled/></td>
                    <td id="Cost" class="dollarLeft">'              . '<input class="text-right" id="cost-' . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Cost"]              . '" /></td>
                    <td id="Labor Hours">'      . '<input class="text-right"                                id="laborHours-'    . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Labor Hours"]       . '" /></td>
                    <td id="Total Hours">'      . '<input class="text-right totalHours-' . $tableNum . '"   id="totalHours-'    . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Total Hours"]       . '" disabled/></td>
                    <td class="dollarRight" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0; width:20px;">' . '<input class="text-center text-muted" value="$"  disabled/></td>
                    <td id="Material Cost" class="dollarLeft">' . '<input class="text-right" id="materialCost-'     . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Material Cost"]     . '" disabled/></td>
                    <td class="dollarRight" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0; width:20px;">' . '<input class="text-center text-muted" value="$"  disabled/></td>
                    <td id="Labor Cost" class="dollarLeft">'        . '<input class="text-right" id="laborCost-'    . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Labor Cost"]        . '" disabled/></td>
                    <td class="success dollarRight" width="1%" style="padding-left:0">' . '<input class="text-muted" value="$"  disabled/></td>
                    <td id="Total Cost" class="success dollarLeft">' . '<input class="text-right totalCost-' . $tableNum . '"   id="totalCost-'     . $qtyRow . '"      value="'    . $row["Total Cost"]        . '" disabled/></td>
                    <td id="Item Number">'      . '<input class="text-left"                                             value="'    . $row["Item Number"]       . '" disabled /></td>
                </tr>
            ';
            update($tableNum);
            $qtyRow = $qtyRow + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what the page looks like now:

[image]

Comment: You should provide the structure of the tables that are read/affected by this operation. I suppose the answer is going to revolve around a single or couple of pure-SQL statements "insert into ... select ...", but it's hard to say without that info.

Comment: What do you want? 1. Get all tables. 2. From each table get all col and rows and display them in html page?

Comment: I have the tables displaying properly. I need to loop through those tables to look for any changes, and reinsert them to the database. My table is a simple one, please see the updated information above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the database with news values from a form in html?
you could use the name field in the input like name="tablename-columnname-rownumber", then in post php

```
foreach($_POST as $key=> $value){
    $array = preg_split("/-/",$key);
    if(count($array)==3) // if had 3 values
    {
        // update table $array[0] set $array[1] = $value where id = $array[2]
        // update table (table name) set (column name) = (value from post) where id = (row number)
    }
}
```

but is better if you put all in an array and just do one update by row

```
$arraytemp = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=> $value){
    $array = preg_split("/-/",$key);
    if(count($array)==3) // if had 3 values
    {
        $arraytemp[$array[0]][$array[2]][$array[1]]=$value;
    }
}
foreach($arraytemp as $tablename => $tabledata){
    $query = "update ".$tablename;
    foreach($tabledata as $id => $columndata){
        foreach($columndata as $columnname => $value){
            $query .=' set '.$columnname'='.$value.';
        }
        $query.=' where id='.$id;
        //exceute query
    }
}
```

(i don't try it, just is what came to my mind, hope it works)

Comment: How would I use something like this if I did not know how many rows there would be?

Comment: it's dinamically... you don't need to know how many rows or cols do you have... in your example you have to add the name like I say before (I did this a LOT of times)